# Select relacionado a outro select, puxando dados do banco

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados, html-select

Necessito criar um formulário que puxa as opções do banco sql. Até aí tudo bem, eu fiz um while dentro de uma consulta em php;

```
echo '<SELECT NAME = "setor">';
    while ( $temp = $setores->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo '<OPTION>'.$temp['nome'];  
    } 
echo '</SELECT>';
```

Porém preciso que um segundo select só apresente as informações de acordo com a opção selecionada no primeiro select.

Então por exemplo, se neste select o usuário selecionar ''filmes'', o proximo select deve exibir os filmes existentes no banco, se ele selecionar ''series'', ele retorna as series registradas, e assim por diante.

Qual a forma mais simples em que eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: O projeto tem JQuery ou só javascript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No evento onChange do seu select, crie um método e faça uma busca em ajax para popular o segundo select.

Algo parecido com isso:

```
$('.select1').on('change', function(){

    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            var html = '';

            $.each(data, function(){
                html += "<option value='"+this.id+"'>"+this.texto+"</option>";
            });

            $('.select2').html(html);
        }
    })

})
```

Lembrando que no PHP você deve retornar um json para o JS:

> echo json_encode($arrRetorno);